# Android JNI in C++ Builder

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, rad-studio

I'm searching for using Android JNI on C++ Builder, and I saw this code:

```
   private void doPhotoPrint() {
       PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(getActivity());
       photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               R.drawable.droids);
       photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap);
   }
```

That's a Java code to print (in a thermal printer) a bitmap and I need to use it in C++ Builder, but I don't have idea how to convert it. I saw doing other things by `intents` or even JNI. I don't want recommendations or something, neither a done code (saying this to avoid judgments that my question is for recommendations), but I want something like this code to help create a function.

PS: I didn't found any documentation about Android JNI.

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```cpp
_di_JPrintHelper photoPrinter = TJPrintHelper::JavaClass->init(TAndroidHelper::Activity);
photoPrinter->setScaleMode(TJPrintHelper::JavaClass->SCALE_MODE_FIT);
_di_JBitmap bitmap = TJBitmapFactory::JavaClass->decodeResource(TAndroidHelper::Context->getResources(), /*R.drawable.droids*/...);
photoPrinter->printBitmap(StringToJString("droids.jpg - test print"), bitmap);
```

I don’t know if Embarcadero has already imported the `TJPrintHelper` and `TJBitmapFactory` classes (do a grep of Embarcadero’s `Androidapi...` header files). If not, you can simply use [Java2OP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Java2OP.exe,_the_Native_Bridge_File_Generator_for_Android) to import them manually.

I don’t know how to translate `R.drawable.droids` to Embarcadero’s JNI framework. `decodeResource()` wants the integer resource ID of the `droids` image.  You will have to track that one down yourself.

Comment: I saw on Embarcadero's Androidapi header files and `TJPrintHelper` is not there. When you say "use Java2OP to import them manually", where can I get `TJPrintHelper` to do it?

Comment: @Que44 I have never used Java2OP myself, but it should be simple enough to just tell it to import the [androidx.print.PrintHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/print/PrintHelper) class and it will generate the `TJPrintHelper` class for you.